# swapping multiple items in list

Tags: python, list

I want to swap items in a list but having two words ('go', 'chargers') always swap and come to get an example:

```
>lst = ['hello', 'go', 'hi', 'chargers']
>lst = ['hello', 'go', 'chargers', 'hi']
```

I can use list assignments:

```
lst[2], lst[3] = lst[2], lst[3]
```

but generalizing it, how would it work such as

```
['hello', 'go', 'sun', 'chargers', 'good', 'go', 'can', 'chargers']
['hello', 'go', 'chargers','sun', 'good', 'go', 'chargers', 'can']
```

how would I pair up all the 'go' 'chargers'

Comment: would enumerate would to find all the values = 'go' and 'chargers;

Comment: done, would enumerate work? or is the list assignment would be fine, but in a more general way?

Comment: Why does it appear that 'go' is never manipulated or swapped? Are you just swapping either or so they are adjacent, and if both need swapping then swap both? Is there a maximum amount of swaps either could do?

Comment: im only trying to swap the word "chargers" to the index in front of 'go' to techincally speaking the only values swapped is "chargers" and the index after the word 'go'. so if a user inputs any list with out the two words nothing will be swapped

Answer (score 0):

Use `enumerate` on a truncated list and then perform your swap with multi-variable assignment

```
for i, v in enumerate(lst[:-2]):
    if v == 'go' and lst[i + 2] == 'chargers':
        lst[i + 1], lst[i + 2] = lst[i + 2], lst[i + 1]

print(lst) # => ['hello', 'go', 'chargers', 'sun', 'good', 'go', 'chargers', 'can']
```

Comment: I have a question, where did the -2 come from

Comment: @Errick-MichaelSantos I put that in there incase you have a list with only `chargers` in it, `lst[i-2] == 'go'` looks back two indexes to check and make sure that the item there is `go` if its not then we don't perfrom the swap

Comment: This has all kinds of range checking issues.What if the list has one item only? What if the first word in the list is 'chargers' (it will check lst[-2]) etc.

Comment: @jarmod you are right I built this off the standing example I honeslty overlooked that possibility will rework this

Comment: @Errick-MichaelSantos updated should work on all cases

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an equal number of "go" and "chargers" and they're placed randomly, you could use `enumerate` to get their indices and then perform your swap:

```
words = ['hello', 'go', 'sun', 'chargers', 'good', 'go', 'can', 'another word', 'chargers']

go_indices = [i for i, w in enumerate(words) if w == 'go']
charger_indices = [i for i, w in enumerate(words) if w == 'chargers']

for gi, ci in list(zip(go_indices, charger_indices)):
    words[gi + 1], words[ci] = words[ci], words[gi + 1]

print(words)
# ['hello', 'go', 'chargers', 'sun', 'good', 'go', 'chargers', 'another word', 'can']
```

Comment: ok, but theoretically speaking the only function need could be enumerate? assuming we always get the same amount of pairs?

Comment: @Errick-MichaelSantos yes you can manually build your `..._indices` lists with just `enumerate`.

Comment: @Errick-MichaelSantos I see what you mean now. You can simplify the list comprehension considerably to just use `enumerate` and then perform your swap.

Comment: This does not work if there are two "go"s adjacent to each other

Answer (score 0):

Here is an not so elegant solution. First identify the chargers location. Swap each item with chargers location once a go is seen

```
lst = ['hello', 'go', 'go', 'chargers', 'good', 'sun', 'can', 'chargers']
index = 1
# loop opposite to make array, later pop them to get increasing order of sequence
allChargerIndex = [len(lst)-i-1 for i,val in enumerate(lst[::-1]) if val=="chargers"]
while index < len(lst):
    if lst[index-1] == "go":
        chargerIndex = allChargerIndex.pop()
        lst[index], lst[chargerIndex] = lst[chargerIndex], lst[index]
    index += 1
print(lst)
```

Offcourse you can inclose it within a function and try with multiple cases

```
def swapGoAndChargers(lst):
   index = 1
   # loop opposite to make array, later pop them to get increasing order of sequence
   allChargerIndex = [len(lst)-i-1 for i,val in enumerate(lst[::-1]) if val=="chargers"]
   while index < len(lst):
        if lst[index-1] == "go":
            chargerIndex = allChargerIndex.pop()
            lst[index], lst[chargerIndex] = lst[chargerIndex], lst[index]
        index += 1
   return lst

print(swapGoAndChargers(['hello', 'go', 'go', 'chargers', 'good', 'sun', 'can', 'chargers']))
#['hello', 'go', 'chargers', 'go', 'chargers', 'sun', 'can', 'good']
print(swapGoAndChargers(['hello', 'go', 'sun', 'chargers', 'good', 'go', 'can', 'chargers']))
#['hello', 'go', 'chargers', 'sun', 'good', 'go', 'chargers', 'can']
print(swapGoAndChargers(['go', 'hello', 'sun', 'go', 'good', 'chargers', 'can', 'chargers']))
#['go', 'chargers', 'sun', 'go', 'chargers', 'hello', 'can', 'good']
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not suggesting that this is particularly elegant or Pythonic.

```
def go_chargers(lst):
    o = []

    for i in range(0, len(lst)):
        o.append(lst[i])
        if lst[i] == 'go':
            for j in range(i + 2, len(lst)):
                if lst[j] == 'chargers':
                    lst[i+1], lst[j] = lst[j], lst[i+1]
                    break
    return o

print(go_chargers(['go', 'sun', 'chargers', 'good', 'go', 'can', 'chargers']))
# ['go', 'chargers', 'sun', 'good', 'go', 'chargers', 'can']

print(go_chargers( ["Rock", "go", "Stars", "go", "Paper", "chargers", "Scissors", "chargers"]))
# ['Rock', 'go', 'chargers', 'go', 'chargers', 'Stars', 'Scissors', 'Paper']
```

Comment: i tried it with one of my other test cases but it seem like its not taking the second pair.["Rock", "go", "Stars", "go", "Paper", "chargers", "Scissors", "chargers"]

Comment: What is the test case?

Comment: ["Rock", "go", "Stars", "go", "Paper", "chargers", "Scissors", "chargers"]

Comment: Ah, the dangers of starting work without a complete specification. This doesn't match the earlier examples where 'go' and 'chargers' were separated by one word. What is your expected output here? I'm guessing ["Rock", "go", "chargers", "go", "chargers", "Stars", "Scissors", "Paper"].

Comment: @Errick-MichaelSantos I updated the code last night to include your updated request.